# Given: $\log_a 2 = 0.69, \log_a 3 = 1.10$ and $ \log_a 5 = 1.61$, how can you solve $\log_a 30 ? $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Given: $$\log_a 2 = 0.69, \log_a 3 = 1.10, \log_a 5 = 1.61$$ 
How can you solve $$\log_a 30 = ?$$

I am doing Schaum's pre-calculus book, and I can do all exercice in the chapter, but I have no idea how to find this solution. Anyone can help?

Comment: This is how I would see it: Notice how 2, 5, and 5 are all factors of $30$ ? In particular, $30 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$. And therefore
$$
\log 30 = \log (2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5)
$$
and so forth ...

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $2\times3\times5 = 30$

And $\log(xyz) = \log(x) + \log(y) + \log(z)$

Comment: thank you! yes it is one of the property of logs, I didn't realize you could use it like that.